# How do i make sure my mesh stays with the armature after leaving pose mode

Tags: mesh, armature, pose-mode

I've been working on a model for quite awhile now and then I'm asked by the person i'm making to model for to make the legs and arms shorter and the hips/waist thinner. I usually do this in pose mode after making sure everything is weighted correctly and then applying that as the rest pose but i've run into a weird issue i've never had before.
I apply pose as rest pose but when I exit pose mode to go back into texture editing/object mode (I tested them all) the bones will stay where they were in pose mode but the mesh goes back to its original scale. If I was getting paid for this (i'm not) I would usually just delete the parts of the mesh that need reworking and....well..rework them and then redo my weight painting. Is there any way I can get an easy out here and not have to spend another 2 hours remodeling the lower half and arms?

Comment: your method is weird, why don't you bring those corrections in Edit mode? It won't need any weight paint correction...

Comment: because in pose mode i can just scale the bones and the parts of the mesh weighted to the bones will follow and scale automatically. though i've never tried doing this in edit mode, does it work the same way?

Comment: I tried and the mesh doesn't follow when scaling bones in edit mode.

Comment: I'm talking about modifying the mesh itself  ;)

Comment: but i need everything to scale evenly, doing all that manually would take hours no? At that point it would take less time to just remodel the parts that aren't scaled to the desired spec.

Comment: if you scale the bones in Pose mode it won't change the mesh itself, it will just change the pose, I doubt that's what the person you're working with wants. Why would it take hours to change your object in Edit mode? Use options like Proportional editing

Comment: I need the bones to scale as well, and in pose mode it does scale the mesh it jsut doesn't save. I figured out I can use CATS blender plugin to apply pose as rest pose and save the mesh scaling as well. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: I didn't know this addon, but again, you can easily edit your mesh with the Proportional Editing option enabled